# Laravel 5.1 sum on relation table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have the following tables:

```
Schema::create('bc_blueprint', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('user_id')->unsiged();
    $table->string('name', 50);
    $table->string('author_name', 50);
    $table->string('bc_version', 50);
    $table->string('version', 10);
    $table->string('archive_name', 50);
    $table->string('screenshot', 50);
    $table->string('screenshot_optional_0', 50)->nullable();
    $table->string('screenshot_optional_1', 50)->nullable();
    $table->tinyInteger('survival_creative');
    $table->tinyInteger('sizeZ');
    $table->tinyInteger('sizeY');
    $table->tinyInteger('sizeX');
    $table->text('description');
    $table->timestamp('uploaded_at');
});
```

and

```
Schema::create('bc_vote', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('blueprint_id')->unsigned();
    $table->tinyInteger('vote')->unsigned();

    $table
        ->foreign('blueprint_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('bc_blueprint')
        ->onDelete('cascade')
        ->onUpdate('cascade');
});
```

I'm trying to get the `sum` of `vote` field in the `bc_vote` table via a relationship.

The `bc_blueprint` table has the following relation with the `bc_vote` table;

```
public function hasManyBlueprintVote()
{
    return $this->hasMany(BlueprintVote::class, 'blueprint_id', 'id');
}
```

while `bc_vote` has:

```
public function belongsToBlueprint()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Blueprint::class, 'id', 'blueprint_id');
}
```

---

I've tried so far:

```
public function browseSingles(Blueprint $blueprint)
{
    $buildcraftSingles = $blueprint->with([
        'hasManyBlueprintVote' => function ($query)
        {
            $query->select(\DB::raw('sum(vote) as total_votes'));
        }
    ])
        ->get();
```

Which doesn't work(at least the way I think it should).

I've tried doing the same thing in the `bc_blueprint` model:

```
public function hasManyBlueprintVoteTotal() {
    return $this->hasMany(BlueprintVote::class)
        ->select(\DB::raw('sum(bc_vote.vote) as votes'));
}
```

Again nothing. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding how I should do this.

Any pointing in the right direction is appreciated.

---

To sort of answer my own question. I gave up on trying to do it with relationships and went for the looping and adding them part in PHP:

```
$buildcraftSingles
    ->pluck('hasManyBlueprintVote')
    ->map(function ($item, $value)
    {
        $item['total_votes'] = $item->sum('vote');
    });
```

Comment: As a thought, you should be able to do `BlueprintVote::where('blueprint_id', $blueprint->id)->sum('vote');`

Comment: Very true, but I'd have to do that for every item in the `bc_blueprint` table that has a vote. I'm trying to avoid doing a lot of queries if possible. I could also write the sql by hand and do it raw, but I'm also trying to avoid that too.